# Auto-protect questions on HNQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Puzzle-Questions appearing on the **Hot Network Quesion** panel have repeately distorted statistics and meaningful rating on PuzzlingSE. While HNQ is generally a good idea to broaden participation accross the different sites, it seems very counter-productive for this particlar site.

I am wondering, if it would be possible to have puzzling-questions appearing on the HNQ *automatically* comunity-proteceted. i.e. only people with at least 10rep on this site (or a higher limit?) can answer/vote it.

This would still allow the HNQ to lure people to this site, but it would prevent the problem of distorted voting on this site.

Comment: Voting already requires 15 rep. I don't think protection changes that at all.

Comment: In addition to what @f'' said, I don't think we're *that* much more attractive *via the Hot Network Questions page/sidebar* to randos than any other SE site; I haven't seen any activity here that I haven't seen elsewhere to indicate that an influx of "bad answers" is in any way unique or especial.

Comment: To clarify: anyone with the +100 association bonus can vote on and answer an unprotected question. Anyone with the +100 association bonus can still vote on protected questions, but if they want to _answer_, they need to have earned at least 10 reputation _separately_ from the association bonus somewhere else on the site.

Answer (score 14):

I came here via a HNQ. I think it's worth it to bring in new visitors, even if it might temporarily distort voting. Getting my first answer in and accepted is what got me hooked on this site. I would think that stopping other new users from taking part - users who are already SE champs - would stop many valuable players from joining our site.